# Place 1s and 0s

Tags: algorithms

Given N 1's and M 0's i need to put them in a row in such a way that their are no two 0's together and no 3 1's together.How to do this question Please help
If it is not possible than tell that its not possible.

Example : Let N= 10 and M=4 then answer is 11011011011011 and if N= 1 and M=5 then here its not possible.

Constraints : 
N can go upto 10^6 and also M can also go upto 10^6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zeros have to go singly. There are $M-1$ places between the zeros which have to be filled, so that is where the first $M-1$ ones have to go (if you don't have enough, it can't be done). Each place can take up to two ones, and there is a place at each end which can take up to two ones (four altogether) meaning that $M$ zeros can accommodate up to $2M+2$ ones.

You should be able to turn that into an algorithm if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

first put 0s in a line, then we put 1 into them

`x0 0 x1 0 ... 0 xm`

assuming there $x_i$ 1s between $i$th 0 and $i+1$th

then we have $\sum_{i=0}^{m}x_i=n$, $1\leq x_i \leq 2 (1\leq i \leq m-1)$, $x_0 \geq 0$, $x_m \geq 0$

so $m-1 \leq n \leq 2(m+1)$