# Sequence of 0s and 1s containing no two 0s or three 1s in a row

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

How many sequences of 0s and 1s of length 19 are there that contain no two consecutive 0s, and contain no three consecutive 1s?

This is different from the one posted here [Place 1s and 0s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706853/place-1s-and-0s)

Note "How many sequences of 0s and 1s of length 19 are there that contain no three consecutive 1s?" is much easier. My question additionally does not allow two 0s in a row.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you set up the recurrence conditioning on the last few digits?

Comment: I can see the building blocks are 10 or 110. So I tried casework: starting with 0 or starting with 1.  If starting with 0, I can have recursive f(n)= f(n-2) + f(n-3). But if starting with 1, then it has to be 10 or 110 followed by building blocks. Confusion is: can I just add them? Since the sequence length is fixed at 19, how to deal if the last digits is 1?  The blocks will not work. I think I need to think harder here

Comment: I think I'm making some progress. Six cases: 0___________1, 0________11, 10____1, 10____11, 110____1, and 110__________11.  Fill in 10 and 110 in between, with recursive f(n)= f(n-2) + f(n-3). Hopefully I'm not missing anything. But are there better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each positive integer $n$,

- Let $f(n)$ be the number of qualifying sequences of length $n$.$\\[4pt]$

  Let $a(n)$ be the number of qualifying sequences of length $n$ with first term equal to $0$.$\\[4pt]$

  Let $b(n)$ be the number of qualifying sequences of length $n$ with first term equal to $1$.$\\[4pt]$

Clearly we have $f(n)=a(n)+b(n)$.

Our goal is to find $f(19)$.

The functions $a,b$ satisfy the linked recursion
\begin{align*}
a(n)&=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{if}\;n=1\\
b(n-1)&\text{if}\;n > 1\\
\end{cases}
\\[8pt]
b(n)&=
\begin{cases}
1&
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\text{if}\;n=1\\
2&
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\text{if}\;n=2\\
a(n-1)+a(n-2)&\text{if}\;n > 2\\
\end{cases}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Applying the recursion, we get
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19\\
\hline
a(n)&1&1&2&2&3&4&5&7&9&12&16&21&28&37&49&65&86&114&151\\
\hline
b(n)&1&2&2&3&4&5&7&9&12&16&21&28&37&49&65&86&114&151&200\\
\hline
f(n)&2&3&4&5&7&9&12&16&21&28&37&49&65&86&114&151&200&265&351\\
\hline
\end{array}
hence $f(19)=351$.